# When using TypeScript in Visual Studio Code, how do I configure TS warnings to be shown as errors?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

For example, this example

```
async function a() { await null; }
```

has a small warning on await in VS Code

```
'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. ts(80007)
```

How do I make that warning behave like an error in VS Code and `tsc` (be more visible, fail compilation)?

Comment: The warnings are not errors. In particular, this warning tells that `await` can be removed and nothing changes in the code behaviour. The code does not fail when that `await` is present. You should not treat them on the same way as you treat the errors. Some warnings are not necessarily problems. The "issues" that they report can be intentional and assumed by the developer. Or, sometimes, they cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `tsc` to treat this as an error, there would need to be a compiler flag that you could set pertaining to `async-await` which I wasn't able to find looking through their [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

There is, however, a linting rule (assuming you have `eslint` set up) which would cause your linter to complain in precisely this situation. See the [eslint docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/await-thenable.md) for an explanation of how it works.

All of that said, if you really want this behavior specifically. I think you could edit the category of [this diagnostic message](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L4943-L4946) to be `"Error"` in your `node_modules` for `typescript`. That approach feels a bit brittle to me so I would definitely encourage the linter approach!

As far as integrating `eslint` with VSCode, there is a [plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) which should integrate the linting warnings directly into the editor. I suspect you can add this to your VScode directly from their marketplace from within VSCode itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the `rules` object of your `.eslintrc.{js,json,yaml,yml}` include this line

```
'@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': 'error',
```

Make sure you have `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` installed (check your `package.json`).

If you're using VSCode, you can use the [ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) to automatically enforce eslint rules in your editor.